# For $B=\int \lambda d E_\lambda $ and $X$ commutes with every $E_\lambda $, why $BX$ is positive and self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators, functional-calculus

Let $B$ be an unbounded closed operator on a Hilbert space $H$. If $B=\int \lambda d E_\lambda $ is positive self-adjoint and a positive bounded operator $X$ commutes with every $E_\lambda $, then why $BX$ is positive and self-adjoint?

I am struggling in dealing with unbounded operators...

see page 48, line +6 (just consider $p=1$) in  [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/isometries-of-noncommutative-lpspaces/7ECF9AE5715F6C8D8A7BA8EC248B28B7)   . I want to understand from line 5 to line 8.

Comment: I cannot view your link. Can you summarize what is on that page?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts  Basically, what I posted is a summarization. I uploaded the pictures of the paper now. I think I should delete them after discussion.

Comment: I'm afraid that's too much for me to help you with.

Comment: I think you only need to read from the bottom of Page 47 to page 48, line +6 (just consider p=1) ... But I agree that it is not a very small thing. I provided the other pages just in case you need any information.@DisintegratingByParts Even if you cannot help me, I still very appreciate for you helpful discussion.

Comment: mathoverflow.net might be a better place for this question. They're research Mathematicians there, and they would have easy access to your article.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts  Thanks for telling me about this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $B=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)$ is the spectral resolution of the positive selfadjoint operator $B$. However, even in this case, your assertion is not true because $X=-B$ commutes with $B$ and, hence, with every $E(\lambda)$, but $XB=-B^2$ is definitely not positive and selfadjoint.

Comment: thx! How about the case when $X$ is positive?

Comment: @user92646 If B and X are positive and commute, then BX is positive.

Comment: how to show it is self adjoint ？or, it is not？

Comment: @user92646 positive implies selfadjoint, so if both are positive and commute, then it is an easy check to show the adjoint of XB is XB.

Comment: This is what I don't know how to do. I have been dealing with bounded operators. Could u give me a short proof for it？ I really not familiar with unbounded operators.

Comment: I can show that XB is symmetric, I also found many references for it. But I still don't know how to prove that the domains of $XB$ and its adjoint are the same.

Comment: @user92646 : Actually, because $B$ is unbounded, $XB$ may not be selfadjoint. A simple example is $X=E(\lambda)$; in this case $XB$ is essentially selfadjoint, meaning that its closure is selfadjoint (even bounded.)

Comment: So, is BX selfadjoint？ That is what I want. Well, I also want to know whether XB is essentially selfadjoint.

Comment: A positive operator is necessarily symmetric.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Symmetric_operators_and_self-adjoint_operators           But I cannot find any reference saying that it is self adjoint.

Comment: @user92646 : Positive unbounded operators are not necessarily selfadjoint or essentially selfadjoint.